# Accessing dynamic property in F#

Tags: c#-4.0, f#, nancy, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

I was trying to access dynamic property in Nancy. In Nancy if pass parameter in query it comes as dynamic property. How can I access that.

There are many discussion / question about this but every where, first it is of creating dynamic and then consuming it. How can I consume what is already created?

Here are two code snippet

```
public class ParameterModule : NancyModule
    {
        public ParameterModule():base("/{about}")
        {
            this.Get["/"] = (parameters) => "Hello About" + parameters.about;
        }
    }
```

and for F#

```
type ParameterModule() as this = 
    inherit NancyModule("/{about}")
    do this.Get.["/"] <- fun parameters -> "Hello" + parameters?("about") :> obj
```

I can't access about as object don't have that property.

Please let me know if any further information needed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The F# dynamic operator `(?)` allows you to pass string parameters without using the quotes, achieving a similar syntax to C# dynamic, but you need to define it first for your concrete use case, the compiler just provides the syntax. Try this:

```
let (?) (parameters:obj) param =
    (parameters :?> Nancy.DynamicDictionary).[param]

type ParameterModule() as this = 
    inherit NancyModule("/{about}")
    do this.Get.["/"] <- fun parameters -> sprintf "Hello %O" parameters?about :> obj
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for answer. But while implementing this I am getting error like this 
This runtime coercion or type test from type 'a to DynamicDictionary involves an indeterminate type based on information prior to this program point. Runtime type tests are not allowed on some types. Further type annotations are needed.

Comment: Sorry, had to declare parameters as `obj`, I've updated the answer with that fixed

Comment: Done... Thanks... I have selected as correct answer but I have to admit now I am getting why people who uses F# prefers it... It don't make code complicated but even more layman. Even my Mom can understand it.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved problem by typecasting to dynamicdictionary. If there is any better way please let me know. Will keep the question open till then...

Here is the code that solve the issue

```
type ParameterModule() as this = 
    inherit NancyModule("/{about}")
    do this.Get.["/"] <- fun parameters -> (parameters :?> Nancy.DynamicDictionary).["about"].ToString() :> obj
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can get you started http://hubfs.net/topic/None/74053

Comment: I tried... But few interface is not allowing me to inherit from DynamicDictionary in F#.